# How can I do partial derivation for F(y,y') with respect to y'?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This is a part of a question on the master/doctor degree graduate school entrance test for Tokyo Univ. in 2016.

The conditions are below

[image]
( [image] )

[image]

Here is the question.

I have to make a differential equation using y, y', and c.

However, **I don't have any ideas to partially derivate F with respect to y'.**

I can't ignore y in F(y,y') because it has a relationship with y, can I?

Please tell me how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial derivative of F[y,y'] is calculated by treating y as a constant and taking the derivative relative to y'.
In your case:

```
D[y Sqrt[1 + y' ^2], y']
```

[image]

Comment: But if y=(x^2)/2 and y' = x, F((x^2)/2,x) = x^2*sqrt(1+x^2)/2. In this case, I can't ignore x^2 because It can be derivated with respect to x, can I?

Comment: No, if you say `dF[y,y']/dy'` you mean: You treat y and y' as the only variables, independent of what y means.